# Writing to a file in as3 flash develop

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Ive been doing some research and I cant seem to find anything on writing to a file. My initial question was writing a array to a seperate file. But now I am looking for resources on how to write any data such as XML or a array to a file. What I want to do is create a game editor. I want to eventually save that data to a file to be opened later. if anyone can help me that would be great.

Comment: To be read at compile time or run time?

Comment: I would write at run time and read at compile

Comment: what does you array contain ? primitive types(ints,uints, Numbers, Strings, etc. ) or complex types(class instances of some sort) ?

Comment: primitives types. numbers and strings. I would like to create a game editor. and save all the data into an array.

Comment: I figure I can use the embed to read from the file. but what about writing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need at least flash player 10, and use the [save](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html#save()) function from the [FileReference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html) object.

- Official [doc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html)
- [another example](http://jeanphiblog.media-box.net/dotclear/index.php?2008/09/24/301-flash-cs4-filereference-save)

Comment: if this is the best solution for writing to a file in flex sdk. Then its a buyable solution for me. Thanks