# How to perform file read write operation in flex web application?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flex4.5

How to perform file read write operation on server in flex web application?
Please guide.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300850/writing-to-a-file-in-as3-flash-develop

Comment: Hi, my requirement is little bit different, i want to save my file data on server not on my local system and also i do not want to give him browser file option.

Answer (score 5):

Well it all depends on. Fileread operation is possible in a web application, but filewrite has to be solved with a server side language, like php.

Generally, for reading you can use [URLStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html), this reads a file into a stream. The easiest usage is:

```
var ldr:URLStream = new URLStream();
ldr.addEventListener("complete", ldrDone);
ldr.load(new URLRequest(URL_OF_YOUR_FILE));

function ldrDone(evt:*):void
{
     //store the file in a bytearray
     var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
     evt.target.readBytes(bytes);
     trace(bytes);
}
```

To write files, use php or whatever script. How to write this and what to include in the code really depend on your project.

For flash-related file reading (like loading a swf, or supported image formats, mostly jpg, gif, png natively), use the [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) class.

For text files and xmls, use the [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) class.

If you have more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi sir, If i am recording sound in Flex web application then the data store on server or on local system? Basically i want to create a application which can record user voice notes. So in application process when user recorded his voice note then i need to save it on server [in file or in database]. I am able to record user voice note but i am not able to finding out solution for saving that data on server. Please guide. Many thanks for your support

Comment: How do you "store" the voicenote? Do you use a premade library for it? If your application works without a living internet connection, then I guess the answer for your first question is that the data is "stored" on the local system. Though, I guess it is "stored" rather in the memory. So, can you tell how do you store it? Is it a ByteArray?

Answer (score 2):

Depends completely on your backend server technology.  PHP, Java, ASP.NET?  Either way you use the same server side documentation tutorial on your server side as handling a file upload.  On the flex side FileReference.upload does the trick.

See: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_7.html

http://www.flex888.com/296/9-flex-file-upload-examples-visited.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/file_upload.html

Comment: I got a way, how can i do that. 
Many Thanks for your support.